# I'm using the Google Calendars API with Django, where do I get my token and refresh_token?

Tags: python, django, google-calendar-api, django-allauth

I'm trying to do something like what's shown below. However, I can only see my client ID and secret key on the developers console. I wasn't sure about the token, but I tried creating an API key and passing that in. However, I have no clue where to get the refresh_token. I've included a screen cap of my developer console.

We're using django-allauth, and I know that you can set social account tokens in the Django admin, is that what I would need to do?

```
 from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
    from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
    
creds = Credentials(
    token='token here',
    refresh_token='refresh token here',
    scopes=['scopes', 'listed', 'here'],
    token_uri='https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',

    client_id='client_id',
    client_secret='client secret'
)
creds.expiry = timezone.make_naive(self.token.expires_at)
if not creds.valid or creds.expired:
    creds.refresh(Request())
```

[image]

Comment: The refresh token is created as part of the OAuth flow. Did you try running the script and did you get any errors? Did you try out following the [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/python) first to get a feel for it?

Comment: Yeah, the quickstart code didn't seem sufficient for getting it working server-side. It seems that I need to get the tokens from all-auth's SocialAccount model, though I'm struggling a little with that.

Comment: Sorry I am a bit confused, what are you trying to do exactly? Have you managed to complete an OAuth flow with only Google stuff? I suggest you do the quickstart, it doesn't take long but will show you how it works, best way to learn. As I said before, the refresh tokens are created as part of the first authentication you do, so you don't generate them via the console, they get made automatically. I am not sure where all-auths social account stuff comes into this. Can you clarify? Maybe refer to [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) too